# Redshift regexp_substr

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to replicate this regex pattern to regexp_substr. I want to capture the second group.

```
'(\?)(.*?)(&|$)'
```

I have tried this

```
regexp(my_url, '\\?.*?&|$')
```

And some similar variations of the above, but I have been getting the errror:
`ERROR: XX000: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occured while parsing the regular expression: '\?.*?>>>HERE>>>&|$'.`

Comment: Try `'(\?)([^&]*)'`

Comment: Maybe the lazy quantifier `.*?` is not supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Amazon Redshift [supports only POSIX regex](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html), you need to use greedy quantifiers rather than lazy ones, but with a *negated character class*:

```
regexp(my_url, '\\?([^&]*)')
```

The pattern matches:

- `\?` - a question mark
- `([^&]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `&`