# Using Regular Expressions in Redshift to get the word prior to matched pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Using Regexp_substring() find the word just preceding the word 'OF' (1st occurrence). The below code is not working as Redshift does not seem to support non-greedy pattern matching.

Please help

```
select regexp_substr('SAFETY COUNCIL OF PALM BEACH COUNTY, INC. ','[[:print:]].*?\\sOF\\s')

Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'rint:]].*?>>>HERE>>>\sOF\s'.
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'rint:]].*?>>>HERE>>>\sOF\s'.
  code:      8002
  context:   T_regexp_init
  query:     0
  location:  funcs_expr.cpp:189
  process:   padbmaster [pid=74292]
  -----------------------------------------------

  Where: SQL function "regexp_substr" statement 1
```

I am currently using this approach which is shabby and believe there should be a better approach

```
select 'SAFETY OF COUNCIL OF PALM OF BEACH COUNTY, INC. ' as name, regexp_instr(name,'\\sOF\\s',1) as ind1,substr(name,1,ind1-1) as name_2,regexp_replace(name_2,regexp_substr(name_2,'.*\\s'),'')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redshift regexp\_substr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495580/redshift-regexp-substr)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I don't think its a duplicate of the other question, I have modified the Title to best represent the issue. Thanks

Comment: FYI, that linked issue includes a way of achieving the result with control of greediness.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality I usually use [split_part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) function. Same works in Postgresql.

```
select split_part('SAFETY COUNCIL OF PALM BEACH COUNTY, INC. ', 'OF',1)
```