# REGEXP_SUBSTR function in Redshift does not return expected value

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I have a table with column called URL. I am trying to extract different parts of URL using `REGEX_SUBSTR` function in Redshift.

```
URL                                             Expected_output
------------                                 
www.abcd.com/first-name                      |   first-name
www.abcd.com/another-name/some-details/other |   another-name
www3.abcd.com/some-name/                     |   some-name
form.abcd.com/another-first-name             |   another-first-name
```

So the intention is to extract the first slug after the domain name

I tried
`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('www.abcd.com/slug-name', '(www|www3|form)[.]abcd[.][^/]+/([^/#?]+)',1,2)`

Output
`www.abcd.com/slug-name`

Comment: What if you use `REGEXP_SUBSTR('www.abcd.com/slug-name', '[^/]+',1,2)`? Or do you need to match only in specific context?

Comment: Please provide feedback on exact context you want a match to occur, it is important here since this regex engine does not seem to support non-capturing groups. Do you need to check for `(www|www3|form)`?

Comment: Yes, I would need to check that this is a valid URL starting with `www|www3|form`

Comment: Then I do not think you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` since it can only extract the *first* capturing group contents, and the others are ignored, and since it uses POSIX regex standard, no non-capturing groups are supported. You need to use a two-step solution.

Comment: Got it. By 2 step do you mean using a UDF?

Comment: No idea, I just checked the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) and see that the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` solution won't work for you even if you add `e` as the parameters option.

Comment: Try `REGEXP_REPLACE('www.abcd.com/slug-name', '^(www3?|form)\\.abcd\\.[^/]+/([^/#?]+).*', '\\2')`

Comment: Is `\\2` intended? It gives me syntax error?

Comment: The point is that we need a backreference to Group 2 in the replacement pattern. If `'\\2'` does not work, try `'$2'`. The docs do not contain any hint on the backreference syntax.

Comment: Understood. No. It only expects int value. Hence it doesn't work. Anyway, thanks for you help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Hm, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50711245/3832970) suggests `'$2'` syntax. Why `int`? Are you trying it with `REGEXP_SUBSTR`? It is `REGEXP_REPLACE`

Comment: oh sorry, you are right. I was using `REGEX_SUBSTR`. `REGEX_REPLACE` works for this case

Comment: If there is no match, REGEXP_REPLACE will keep the original string, is it OK or do you want to remove the whole string?

Comment: I guess it should be ok. Currently, I am trying it out with different data that I have and seeing if there are any other edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need several groupings in the pattern with the first one defining the expected match context (so, you do not need to extract the first group content), and `REGEXP_SUBSTR` only supports the first group extraction using the `e` modifier, you have to fall back to `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

One note: `REGEXP_REPLACE` removes the matches and if a string has no match, it will remain there as is. `REGEXP_SUBSTR` would return a blank value.

So, you may consider

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('www.abcd.com/slug-name', '^(www3?|form)\\.abcd\\.[^/]+/([^/#?]+).*', '$2')
```

Or, to remove the no match entries text (note the `|.+` added at the end):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('www.abcd.com/slug-name', '^(www3?|form)\\.abcd\\.[^/]+/([^/#?]+).*|.+', '$2')
```

So, `^(www3?|form)\\.abcd\\.[^/]+/([^/#?]+).*` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(www3?|form)` - Group 1: `www` and an optional `3`
- `\.abcd\.` - `.abcd.` substring
- `[^/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `([^/#?]+)` - Group 2 (referred to via the `$2` backreference in the replacement pattern): 1 or more chars other than `/`, `#` an `?`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible

The `|.+` says "or any 1+ chars". That is, remove the whole text if the first alternative found no matches.

Answer (score -1):

You can ignore anything up to the first forward slash, capture the group after the first and up to the second (if present). In the capture group, you want to get anything with characters (possibly not upper-case), hyphens and underscores. I found '\w-' matches both underscores and hyphens.

Try this expression:

```
^.*?\/([\w-]+)\/?.*
```

I tested this on the following strings:

```
www.abcd.com/first-name                     
www.abcd.com/another-name/some-details/other 
www3.abcd.com/some-name/                    
form.abcd.com/another-first-name
form.abcd.com/another_first-name
form.abcd.com/anotherfirst-name
```

and I used the [tool on Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) to give me these matches:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-44    www.abcd.com/first-name                     
Group 1.    13-23   first-name
Match 2
Full match  45-90   www.abcd.com/another-name/some-details/other 
Group 1.    58-70   another-name
Match 3
Full match  91-135  www3.abcd.com/some-name/                    
Group 1.    105-114 some-name
Match 4
Full match  136-168 form.abcd.com/another-first-name
Group 1.    150-168 another-first-name
Match 5
Full match  169-201 form.abcd.com/another_first-name
Group 1.    183-201 another_first-name
Match 6
Full match  202-233 form.abcd.com/anotherfirst-name
Group 1.    216-233 anotherfirst-name
```

Comment: `Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '^.*?>>>HERE>>>/([w-]+)/?'`

Comment: Some similar error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495580/redshift-regexp-substr

Comment: Ah, I was afraid there would be a difference in Regex versions. I'm not sure, perhaps try replacing the lazy '.*?' with '[\w.]+', I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Redshift and don't have a way to test it.

Comment: @JamesBaker Your regex won't work with OP code. You need to include the usage example.